# Verificar se uma variável é do tipo de função

Tags: javascript

Digamos que eu tenha uma variável qualquer, definida como:

```
var xpto = function() {/* Faz alguma coisa */};
```

Eu preciso comparar se o tipo da variável é uma função, ou seja:

```
function isFunction(f) {if (f is (function type?)) {/* ... */}};
isFunction(xpto);
```

Dessa forma, como posso verificar se a variável `xpto` é do tipo `function`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sabendo que:

```
typeof xpto // "function"
```

Talvez fazer:

```
function isFunction(f) {
  return (typeof f === "function")
}
```

Seja uma opção para o que você quer.
Espero ter ajudado.

Answer (score 4):

Darlei, para isso existe a função **typeof** do javascript.

Veja um pequeno exemplo:

```js
let fun = () => {
  console.log("É uma função");
}

if (typeof(fun) == "function") {
  console.log("É uma função! =)")
}
```

> Referência:
>   https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof